# Outlier Detection Using tsoutliers() show wrong outliers in R

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, outliers

I am trying perform outlier cleaning using tsoutliers() function using R. I have a time
Series as well as the summary of that time series is given below:

`dput(X1)`:

```
structure(c(450, 235, 203, 230, 86, 86, 133, 113, 206, 282, 731, 
564, 266, 183, 123, 189, 97, 172, 126, 93, 85, 146, 152, 789, 
448, 218, 121, 161, 73, 65, 41, 28, 48, 52, 185, 668, 280, 116, 
99, 75, 32, 135, 56, 54, 79, 109), tsp = c(2019, 2022.75, 12), class = "ts")
```

This is the documentation for this function by the author:
https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tsoutliers/

The Summary of this time series is :

[image]

As you can see the 3rd Quartile value is 215, 1st Quartile is 85.25 and IQR is 129.75
Which means while considering **Q1-1.5*IQR** is **(-109.375)** & **Q3+1.5IQR** is **(409.625)** should be the range and over and above
that value it should be outliers. But when I run `tsoutliers(X1)`

[image]

The index position which I get are:

[image]

The index which is returned as outliers is **6,10,11,12,13,23,25** and the respective values are
this makes no sense as **86,282,266,152** cant be outlier as it is well within the quartile range
also this doesnt mention the **668** at the index of **36**.

[image]

Can someone help me out. I really am out of my depth here. Am I doing something wrong here.
If so can someone correct the code.
This is a time series monthly data.

The code I have written is given below:

```
library(readxl)
Sales<- read_excel("C:/X/X/X/X/Sales.xlsx")
View(Sales)

X1 <- ts(data = Sales$`XYZ_1`,
               frequency = 12,
               start = c(2019,01),
               end = c(2022,10))

summary(X1)
autoplot(X1)
tsoutliers(X1)
```

Comment: Rather than posting screen shots,  copy text from the console, and paste the results into your question.   More important:  always provide the package name to which your functions belong.  in this case,  `forecast`

Answer (score 0):

Reading from the vignette you linked to,

> The procedure decomposes the time series into trend, seasonal and
> remainder components: yt=Tt+St+Rt
>
> The seasonal component is optional, and it may containing several
> seasonal patterns corresponding to the seasonal periods in the data.
> The idea is to first remove any seasonality and trend in the data, and
> then find outliers in the remainder series, Rt .

This suggests to me that the outlier values don't fall on the expected curve, rather than not falling within the overall quartile distribution.  Try graphing your data and then decomposing (with other `forecast` tools to see that the  S, T, and R components might look like.

This is definitely **not** a simple "curve fit and identify points greater than sigma from the fit" tool.

Comment: I am sorry. I was not able to understand what you mentioned. Could you please explain it in a bit simpler way. What do you mean by S,T & R.

Comment: @user20203146   read the vignette and the manual for this R package.